# Loop that can show the min and max date for each month with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

[Image sample of the datetimedata... It goes down to 4/1/2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOBhV.png)

```
import pandas as pd    
import calendar
from datetime import date

sd = '2021-12-01'
ed = '2022-03-31'
 
date_range = pd.date_range(sd,ed,
              freq='MS').map(lambda x: (x.year, x.month)).tolist()

def get_dates(year, month):
  return (date(year, month, 1).strftime("%d-%b-%Y"),
          date(year,
                month,
                calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
                ).strftime("%d-%b-%Y"))

[get_dates(year, month)
for year, month in date_range]
 
df2 = pd.read_csv('datetimedata.csv')
df2.loc[:,'timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.loc[:,'timestamp'])
df2 = df2.loc[(df2['timestamp'] >= sd)
                       & (df2['timestamp'] <= ed)]
```

When I write to get the min and max in my console it gives this answer below:

```
df2.timestamp.min()
Out[102]: Timestamp('2021-12-01 00:00:00')
 
df2.timestamp.max()
Out[103]: Timestamp('2022-03-31 00:00:00')
```

However I wanted it so that if I were to stop the loop after the first run the max would be (2021-12-31 00:00:00). Then when I have the loop going through March then the codes finishes running, max should be 2022-03-31 and min should be 2022-03-01. I just want it to loop through each month showing the min and max date for each consecutive month.

Comment: the code reads a file `datetimedata.csv`, so please suppy this file or its contents in otder to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @D.L I added a sample image of the data

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), and please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need `date_range` at all. Why not simply grouping by month of `df2['timestamp']`?

```py
# example setup for df2: random timestamps (not even at any particular frequency)

n = 100
s, e = '2021', '2022-04-01'
np.random.seed(0)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp': np.random.uniform(pd.Timestamp(s).value, pd.Timestamp(e).value, n)
})
df2['timestamp'] = df2['timestamp'].apply(pd.Timestamp)
```

Now:

```py
out = df2.groupby(
    pd.Grouper(freq='MS', key='timestamp')
)['timestamp'].agg([min, max, 'size'])

>>> out
                                     min                           max size
timestamp                                                                  
2021-01-01 2021-01-03 03:16:28.560081408 2021-01-30 04:29:26.376463360    7
2021-02-01 2021-02-02 07:42:49.519875328 2021-02-28 15:52:30.613407488   11
2021-03-01 2021-03-01 23:13:57.566841344 2021-03-31 10:40:45.802366208    7
2021-04-01 2021-04-06 00:56:03.035600128 2021-04-26 05:56:39.479043840    4
2021-05-01 2021-05-01 08:56:50.223057152 2021-05-25 22:46:22.658766336    8
2021-06-01 2021-06-13 13:49:34.587356672 2021-06-24 11:10:52.988078848    4
2021-07-01 2021-07-08 11:45:06.840360704 2021-07-29 23:21:16.688887296    8
2021-08-01 2021-08-01 04:06:49.102527232 2021-08-29 15:31:57.085326080    5
2021-09-01 2021-09-05 22:07:27.689974016 2021-09-24 20:43:16.493253888    8
2021-10-01 2021-10-02 06:10:33.840128512 2021-10-31 16:07:16.857132288   11
2021-11-01 2021-11-02 03:21:55.930429184 2021-11-22 22:17:35.048308992    6
2021-12-01 2021-12-03 08:45:29.833306112 2021-12-30 14:48:41.476487936    6
2022-01-01 2022-01-09 13:14:45.851782144 2022-01-31 20:31:57.571878912    5
2022-02-01 2022-02-10 18:09:40.206745088 2022-02-27 19:54:52.119116032    3
2022-03-01 2022-03-06 09:43:44.462566912 2022-03-26 17:02:32.321784320    7
```

#### Addendum

If you really want to have an explicit loop that goes through the months, you can do so as well:

```py
for month, g in df2.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='MS', key='timestamp')):
    break

>>> month
Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00', freq='MS')

>>> g['timestamp'].max()
Timestamp('2021-01-30 04:29:26.376463360')
```

#### Edit

As per the request in the comment, in order to truncate the data to a specific time window:

```py
sd = '2021-12-01'
ed = '2022-03-31'

out = df2.truncate(before=sd, after=ed).groupby(
    pd.Grouper(freq='MS', key='timestamp')
)['timestamp'].agg([min, max, 'size'])
```

Comment: Where would you add the for month, g in df2.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='MS', key='timestamp')):
    break code at in the orginal?

Comment: I wouldn't. I would use the first expression (`df2.groupby(...).agg(min, max, 'size')`) and I would have in one fell swoop the min and max dates for all the months.

Comment: Okay, is there a way where you incorporate the variables sd and ed and if so how would that process look?

Comment: Oh, sure, see my edit at the end. Simply use `df2.truncate(before=sd, after=ed)` instead of `df2`.